# password requirements using awk command

Tags: bash, scripting

My code does run but I think there is an error in the bold part (equation). Please hep me to correct the code.

checking the the strength of the passwords in a text file and the strength are,

1. 9 or more characters in length
2. At least should contain one digit
3. At least should contain one uppercase letter

If it meets the requirements print "Successful" else "unsuccessful".

awk 'BEGIN { FS=" " ; OFS="\t";}
**NR>1{   if (($2)length -ge 8 && $2 ~ "[[:digit:]]" && $2 ~ "[[:upper:]]")**

Comment: _My code does run_  : **It doesn't**. You have a missing closing quote and a missing closing curly brace, and even if I add them, I still get a syntax error. Post code which we can copy and paste into the command line for reproducing the issue.

Comment: _"At least should contain one uppercase letter"_ implies than you should also check for _"At least should contain one lowercase letter"_, no ?

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax of `length()` wrong, it's a function whose argument inside the parentheses is the string whose length you want returned.

Also, `-gt` is shell syntax; Awk uses the regular `>=` for numeric comparisons. (You can't easily use the `>` symbol in the shell because it's reserved for redirection; but Awk is a separate language entirely.)

Finally, your Awk script seems to lack any action after the `if`, including even a closing curly brace for the opening curly brace.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { FS=" " ; OFS="\t";} NR>1{ if (length($2) >= 8 && $2 ~ "[[:digit:]]" && $2 ~ "[[:upper:]]") print }'
```

The script could be refactored to exploit the fact that `{ print }` is already the default action, and all your conditions apply to the current input line.

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { FS=" " ; OFS="\t";} NR>1 && length($2) >= 8 && $2 ~ "[[:digit:]]" && $2 ~ "[[:upper:]]"'
```